# tableView.hidden breaks other elements

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, mkmapview, uisearchbar

I have in my iOS app a `mapView`, and a `UISearchBar` to search locations and center the user on it. The results of my search are made by autocompletion and displayed in a `tableView`.

I had trouble with it, when i clicked on cancel, it displayed me all of my datas in the `tableView`.

So I implemented this function:

```
func searchBarCancelButtonClicked(searchBar: UISearchBar) {
    searchTableView.hidden = true
}
```

But the render of that function makes this:

[image]
[image]

I don't know (and don't know how to see) if my `mapView` is still under the black screen.

By the way, if I delete my cancel button function, and search something, if I click on `Cancel` it will display something like this:

[image]

To hide my `tableView` again, I have to make another search, than delete it with the little cross button, then cancel.

My code, of the autocompletion search, is like that:

```
func initTableView() {
    searchTableView.delegate = self
    searchTableView.dataSource = self
    searchTableView.scrollEnabled = true
    searchTableView.hidden = true
}

func searchBarSearchButtonClicked() {
    searchTableView.hidden = false
    searchBar.resignFirstResponder()
    dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    searchBar(searchBar, textDidChange: searchBar.text!)
}

func searchBar(_searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
    searchTableView.reloadData()
    searchAutocompleteEntriesWithSubstring(searchText)
}

func searchAutocompleteEntriesWithSubstring(substring: String) {
    searchBar.filtredDatas.removeAll(keepCapacity: false)
    for curString in searchBar.datas {
        let myString:NSString! = curString.title! as NSString

        let substringRange :NSRange! = myString.rangeOfString(substring)

        if (substringRange.location == 0) {
            searchBar.filtredDatas.append(curString)
        }
    }
}
```

This is from my `ViewController.swift` file. 
My `searchBar` variable is a custom class that contains an `NSArray` of datas and another of `fileterDatas`.

```
@IBOutlet weak var mapView: UGOMapController!
@IBOutlet var searchTableView: UITableView!
@IBOutlet weak var searchBar: UGOSearchBar!
```

Thanks for your help. 
If you need more of my code, I can edit this post.

**Edit:**

Here are my UITableView functions, used for searchTableView

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return searchBar.filtredDatas.count
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let autoCompleteRowIdentifier = "AutoComplete"
    var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(autoCompleteRowIdentifier) as UITableViewCell!

    if cell != nil {
        let index = indexPath.row as Int
        if (searchBar.filtredDatas.count > 0) {
        cell!.textLabel!.text = searchBar.filtredDatas[index].title
        }
    }
    else {
        cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Value1, reuseIdentifier: autoCompleteRowIdentifier)
    }
    return cell!
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    let selectedCell : UITableViewCell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)!
    searchBar.text = selectedCell.textLabel!.text
}
```

And my hierarchy:

[image]

And my viewController inspector:

[image]
[image]

Comment: You can inspect the views hierarchy in Xcode: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/Xcode_Overview/ExaminingtheViewHierarchy.html

I would also suggest to check whether `searchTableView` is set correctly.

Comment: I just checked the views hierarchy (thanks for the tips ^^) but no, everything is correct on that point... On the other hand, I have my numberOfRowInSection / cellForRowAtIndex ... functions. I kind of custom them so it is possible, but I'm totally new on swift to truly see what is wrong in it. Should i put it in the post ?

Comment: Yes, please. Knowing the view hierarchy and how you set the outlets might help

Comment: Here it is. Thanks :)

Comment: Could you please also show the Connections Inspector for your `ViewController` ? I wonder if you have accidentally connected tableview and mapView to the same outlet.

Comment: I think i already linked that? Above the "edit" word ?

Comment: Not the view hierarchy, but the Connections Inspector: http://ptgmedia.pearsoncmg.com/images/chap5_9780672335761/elementLinks/05fig20.jpg

Comment: Here it is. I think the grey "view" link is a bad sign ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 3 different outlets connected to the table view.

It means that when you hide the tableView, you also hide the view, because it's connected to the same `Search Table View`

You have to make sure that you connect your table view just to one outlet.

**Edit**

To be more precise:

1. You have to change your view controller from UITableViewController to UIViewController.
2. The `view` outlet will be connected to viewController's `view` property.
3. The `tableView` outlet will be removed, because in a normal UIViewController this property doesn't exist. (It's defined in UITableViewController)
4. `SearchTableView` should be connected to the `searchTableView` property that you define in your view controller.

Comment: Thanks. But how do I link them to other view. Or more like, to what do i link them? And are my tableView and my searchTableView two different things? I just add the picture of every link I can make ^^

Comment: Updated my answer :) Hope it helps.
This post might also be helpful in terms of how to set up a table view in a normal UIViewController in xib: https://www.weheartswift.com/how-to-make-a-simple-table-view-with-ios-8-and-swift/

Comment: But if I change my controller to an UIView, I won't be able to override ly tableView functions. Should I create a UITableViewController file beside ?

Comment: You don't have to override them. Since you are setting your view controller as a delegate and a data source for the table view, you just implement these methods in your view controller. In your case you will just need to remove the `override` keywords :)

P.S. Don't change to `UIView`, change to `UIViewController: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource`

Comment: Ok, I removed the tableView outlet. But i can't link my view to anything else than searchTableView (they propose me to link it to "view", but if I do that it will add a grey searchTableView link).

Comment: You have to recreate the hierarchy in xib as well. You need to add a table view as a subview to the viewController's view. The same with the searchbar. Please follow the link that I posted in my comments above.

Comment: I read it, but hoped I could do it in a more simple way. Well, thanks a lot :)